# Problem of deploying contract with "testRPC" and "remix" : "creation of contract pending ..."

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, testrpc, pending-transactions

When I try to deploy a contract using testRPC and remix, I receive:

creation of contract pending ...

[image]

I tried even the default contract of http://remix.ethereum.org.

**Steps:** First I open `cmd`. Then I type `testrpc`. Then I select `web3 Provider`. And finally press the `Deploy` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is showing that the contract has been successfully deployed.

The latest log messages are going to appear at the bottom.

You have the "creation of Ballot pending..." message, but there is a light white line beneath it where the contract information is then listed with a **status of 1** (successful).